# Formatting XML files in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, xml-parsing

When i try to format a xml file in eclipse it puts each of the fields on a new line. instead i want each property to be on one line. for e.g. now when i press CTRL+SHFT+F, eclipse formats it like this.

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.server.entities">
<class
    name="Branch"
    table="Branch"
>
    <meta attribute="sync-DAO">false</meta>
    <id name="Id"
        type="java.lang.Long"
        column="id"
    >
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

    <property
        name="Created"
        column="created"
        type="timestamp"
        not-null="false"
        length="23"
    />
    <property
        name="LastUpdated"
        column="lastUpdated"
        type="timestamp"
        not-null="false"
        length="23"
    />
    <property
        name="CreatedBy"
        column="createdBy"
        type="java.lang.Long"
        not-null="false"
        length="19"
    />
```

but what i want is

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.kaizen.report.server.entities">
<class name="Branch" table="Branch">
    <meta attribute="sync-DAO">false</meta>
    <id name="Id" type="java.lang.Long" column="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

<property name="Created" column="created" type="timestamp" not-null="false" length="23"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the XML Editor from eclipse.org, go tot he XML Editor preference page and change the options to allow much longer lines and to not split multiple attributes each onto new lines.